# Run code if clicked the button

Tags: javascript, html

There is a possibility, of run code only if clicked the one button? As long as do not click on the button, code is not running, but if is clicked, the code is starting running.

Show the div block if click is button is not working, because code is on the background running, if clicked the button, if no.

Comment: you may have a look to events. have you tried anything?

Comment: show your code rather than act.

Comment: You really need to be more descriptive if you want anyone to be able to help. Do you want to run a certain piece of code once a button is clicked?

Comment: @Abel - Yes. That's exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very confusing, but this might help you: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        alert("Your code is running correctly!");
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: I've tried it and it does not work. I thought of a solution like, for example, when I send a form and thank you for your reply is coming.

Comment: @MeilHelt What have you tried so far? Please add some code in your Question, so we can help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have any code. I used the Ninja Form - Wordpress plugin with run the codes, if clicked the send button (the thanks of reply page is running only, if clicked the send button). But it's so complicated to find a shorter and simpler code/solution.

Comment: We can't help you here on Stack Overflow if you don't have any code to show, or using plugins that you don't understand. Please contact their website for further help: https://ninjaforms.com/contact/

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```js
function a() {
alert("Code ran by you on the click");
}
```

```html
   <button onclick="a();">Button</button>
```